# Insert image in word file in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ms-word

Im trying to automatically make some word file on server using ASP Classic. It works fine but the only problem is when I download the files there is no picture in them instead I get something like place holder. Here is my code:

`set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")`
`Set act = fso.CreateTextFile(server.mappath("/") & file_being_created, true)`

`act.WriteLine("<html xmlns:v=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml""")`
`act.WriteLine("xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office""")`
`act.WriteLine("xmlns:w=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word""")`
`act.WriteLine("xmlns:m=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml""")`
`act.WriteLine("xmlns:css=""http://macVmlSchemaUri"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"">")`
`act.WriteLine("<title>testing</title>")`
`act.WriteLine("<body> " )`
`act.WriteLine("<img src='http://mysite.com/images/pic.jpg' width='800' height='200'/><br />" )`
`act.WriteLine(rsInvoices("invoiceClientID") & "<br />" )`
`act.WriteLine(rsInvoices("invoiceNumber") )`
`act.WriteLine("</body></html>")"`
`act.close`

Any idea to have picture in word file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine. Are you super sure that the image really exists in that url?

Comment: @Yes, Image is there. Just its not getting embedded to the word file.

Comment: In this code, you are linking to the image, not embedding it. My suggestions is to generate a PDF file, it's easier and you have a lot of open-source components and resources to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, what I did to get to this answer was to create a new Word document (using Word 2010), insert a picture from my hard drive, then save the file as an HTML file.  Then I looked at the resulting page and tried to deconstruct what Word was doing.  What I found was that in addition to the HTML `<img>` tag, Word also created a `<v:shape>` element, hidden by a [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Here is what I came up based on your example:

```
<!--[if gte vml 1]>
<v:shape id="Picture1" style="width:800px;height:200px;">
 <v:imagedata src="http://mysite.com/images/pic.jpg"/>
</v:shape>
<![endif]-->
<![if !vml]>
<img src='http://mysite.com/images/pic.jpg' width='800' height='200' v:shapes="Picture1"/>
<![endif]>
```

If you're serving this file as a .doc file, you could save some space and duplication by only including the `<v:shape>` element and leaving out the conditional comments.

```
<v:shape id="Picture1" style="width:800px;height:200px;">
 <v:imagedata src="http://mysite.com/images/pic.jpg"/>
</v:shape>
```

Comment: @Thanks Cheran, This is the one can bring the picture. Just the only problem is when you are online you can see the picture other wise no. That's because you see the picture from the link inside the word file.

Comment: @Jay, that is correct.  I did try embedding the image using the binData element, as described [here](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000106.html), but at least with Word 2010, that apparently only works for XML files and not for HTML.  So far I haven't found a way to embed the image in HTML so that Word understands it.