# Embed image in word file using ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ms-word

Does any body have any idea how to embed picture in word file created with ASP Classic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert image in word file in ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825370/insert-image-in-word-file-in-asp).  Please don't ask the same question twice just because your original one attracted no answers, and had more information than this.

Comment: @Moo, Thanks for your attention, But just I thought first one wasn't clear enough. Since you have time to count my questions, Would you tell me how to solve this issue? ;-)

Comment: I put your code in to an example ASP file, removed the rsInvoices references, change the `'` characters in your image line to `""` instead, ran it, and I see the image in Word.  So, are you sure the URL was right?

Comment: @Moo, I got the answer in the first question you mentioned before. You can check that out. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to generate Word files with ASP once, by far the easiest way (and you can get it looking pretty good this way) is to render an HTML file with your desired content and do it that way.  I can't remember if renaming the HTML file to .doc worked, or if I used a component.  But HTML is probably the way to go.

Comment: That's a rather vague - "I think I did it this way but I am not sure" kinda answer, aka not an answer at all.

Comment: I can easily create word file in ASP. My question is how to embed image in world file. Let me explain you: I make the word file in asp and when I download the file instead of image there is something like place holder is in my word file. I want to have real picture in there.